# Free char*, when passed as a void in C

Tags: c, pointers, casting, char

I have this function

```
void clean_strs(void *p){
    if (!p){
        printf("Clean str ptr that is NULL !!\n");
        fflush(stdout);
        return;
    }
    char *a = (char*)p;
    free(a);
    a = NULL;
}
```

And passing in a pointer like this:

```
char *a = malloc(4*sizeof(char));
// check if memory was allocated
if(a) {
    a = "asd\0";
    clean_strs(a);
    a = NULL;
    if(a) {
        getchar();
    }
}
```

Results in signal SIGABORT. Can someone please explain why casting and freeing pointer that was dynamically allocated is an error?

Comment: Did you mean seg fault?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't free a pointer that was dynamically allocated. You freed a pointer to a constant:

```
a = "asd\0";
```

You just replaced the value you got from `malloc` with a pointer to a string constant. You can't `free` any pointer but one you got from `malloc`.

You probably wanted:

```
strcpy (a, "asd");
```

Comment: So I cannot just assign strings to allocated char*? @David

Comment: @Batousik You can, but it really does the assignment when what you wanted was a copy. You didn't want to change the value of `a`, you wanted to copy a string into the memory that `a` points to, which is just using its value, not assigning it.

Comment: and what about \0 character? Or is it automatically at position 4?@David

Comment: @Batousik The C language uses \0 to mark the end of a string. String constants are strings.

Comment: @Batousik Although C allows it for historical reasons, you don't want to point char *'s at string literals for exactly this kind of reason.  Instead, you should make sure you only point const char *'s at string literals so that the compiler will warn you if/when your code tries to alter the memory to which the pointer points.  I'd hope compilers these days will warn you when you point a char * at a string literal.